# Unknown server tag 'dnn:DNNGrid'

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I installed the dotnetnuke Blog module and am getting an error when I try to manage it:

```
Error: is currently unavailable.
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Unknown server tag 'dnn:DNNGrid'.
---> System.Web.HttpParseException: Unknown server tag 'dnn:DNNGrid'.
```

I looked on their site but couldn't find much of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to upgraded to the latest DNN8 specific release of the Blog module.

https://github.com/DNN-Connect/DNN-Blog/releases

https://github.com/DNN-Connect/DNN-Blog/releases/tag/06.03.00

DNN8 had breaking changes, that required some modules to be recompiled.